# Winzip Legacy Format in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, zip, winzip

I have a script that uses the ZIP command in linux (Ubuntu), and changes the name to make it executable for a certain program.

Now I realized the reason this program was not unzipping and installing it correctly was because it seems to depend on Windows legacy compression Zip 2.0 compatibility. Is there anything I can do to ensure compatibility when using the zip command via linux command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manual, Info-ZIP `zip` archives are incompatible with (older?) PK-ZIP when data is streamed from standard input and/or when the archive > 2 GiB.

The option "-Z deflate" might be useful too (that's the most-supported zip compression method).

Comment: We ended up forcing a software change to the programming opening the zip file. It really wasn't the zip format's problem or my script's issue but rather the actual software using it. I do think this was helpful though Thanks!